# Impedir usuário de salvar informações no banco

Tags: c#

Olá estou usando *Windows FORM C# Visual Studio*, como faço para impedir que o usuário salve as informações no banco sem preencher os campos necessário, ou seja aqueles `(NOT NUL)` do banco tudo isso via código *C#*. Eu tentei com `IF(){}` como está abaixo, mas não deu certo.

```
    void IMPEDIRSALVAR()//Método impedi que o usuário salve as informações
    {
        if (txtNomeAluno.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Não é possivel criar um aluno sem o nome do aluno", "Cadastrando Aluno", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            txtNomeAluno.Focus();
            if (mtbNascimentoAluno.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Não é possivel criar um aluno sem a Data de nascimento", "Cadastrando Aluno", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                mtbNascimentoAluno.Focus();
            }

            if (mkb_Cpf.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Não é possivel criar um aluno sem O CPF do Responsável", "Cadastrando Aluno", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                mkb_Cpf.Focus();
            }
            if (txtRG.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Não é possivel criar um aluno sem o RG do Responsável", "Cadastrando Aluno", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                txtRG.Focus();
            }
            if (mkb_fone_contato.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Não é possivel criar um aluno sem o Fone de contato", "Cadastrando Aluno", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                mkb_fone_contato.Focus();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Salvando");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Todas as respostas de você infelizmente não foram validas. No 1ª txtbox (txtNomealuno) funciona mas se data nascimento e cpf tiver fazio ele continua salvando...

Answer (score 3):

A logica esta' errada. Actualmente, para mostrar "Salvando", basta preencher o nome do aluno - todos os outros campos sao opcionais.

```
if(nomeAluno  == ""){
    //...

    if(campo2  == "")
        //..
    if(campo3 == "")
        //...
}
else {
    //salvar
}
```

Para tornar todos os campos obrigatorios, os *if*s teem de ser *encadeados*, em vez de *nested*:

```
if(nomeAluno == "")
    //...
else if(campo2  == "")
    //..
else if(campo3 == "")
    //...
else {
    //salvar
}
```

Comment: Recomendaria usar `string.Empty` em vez de usar o `""`. Torna o intuito da comparação mais claro.

Answer (score 3):

O que você pode fazer para simplificar a validação é sempre usar o **`return`** dentro de cada **`IF`**.

É mais ou menos o que é sugerido aqui: [Replace Nested Conditional with Guard Clauses](http://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html).

Claro que isso depende bastante também da sua lógica. Segue uma sugestão de código:

```
void IMPEDIRSALVAR()//Método impedi que o usuário salve as informações
{
    if (txtNomeAluno.Text.Equals(string.Empty))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Não é possivel criar um aluno sem o nome do aluno", "Cadastrando Aluno", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
       txtNomeAluno.Focus();
       return;
    }
    if (mtbNascimentoAluno.Text.Equals(string.Empty))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Não é possivel criar um aluno sem a Data de nascimento", "Cadastrando Aluno", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        mtbNascimentoAluno.Focus();
        return;
    }

    // Nenhum erro...
    MessageBox.Show("Salvando");
}
```

Comment: É uma alternativa às cadeias de `else if`. Em ambos os casos ele só salvará se não entrou em nenhum `if`. Vai de quem escreveu o código (preferência por *single point of return*)

Answer (score 2):

Use o método [`IsNullOrEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx) (apesar do check para `null` ser irrelevante conforme [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26722/impedir-usu%c3%a1rio-de-salvar-informa%c3%a7%c3%b5es-no-banco-utilizando-c/26727#comment49856_26727) do [@dcastro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/2360/dcastro)).

Adicionalmente mantenha uma estrutura plana de `ifs`.Se você realmente irá validar tudo exibindo `MessageBox`, `else ifs` impedem que múltiplos erros sejam exibidos de uma única vez).

Finalmente, se você quiser validar também se o texto não é uma cadeia em branco, de uma olhada no método [`IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx) (ou use `txt.Text.All(char.IsWhiteSpace)` se você não quer desperdiçar a checagem por nulos).

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtNomeAluno.Text)) 
{
    MessageBox.Show("Não é possivel criar um aluno sem o nome do aluno", "Cadastrando Aluno", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    txtNomeAluno.Focus();
}
else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(mtbNascimentoAluno.Text))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Não é possivel criar um aluno sem a Data de nascimento", "Cadastrando Aluno", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    mtbNascimentoAluno.Focus();
}
// ....
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Salvando");
}
```

Comment: Embora seja boa pratica usar `string.IsNullOrEmpty`, neste caso em particular, e' irrelevante e nao resolve o problema. `TextBox.Text` nunca e' null.

Comment: @dcastro, mas o método verifica também se é vazio, "orEmpty", por isso a validação dele não está errada!
E se você não percebeu, ele acaba fazendo a mesma coisa que na sua resposta... ;D

Comment: @BrunoCasali Nao disse que a validacao estava errada, disse que era irrelevante. A resposta "use o metodo IsNullOrEmpty" e' uma resposta errada porque nao resolve o problema do OP.

Comment: @dcastro, [você tem razão](http://blog.icsharp.net/2007/12/can-textboxtext-ever-be-null.html). Eu não sabia que era impossível atribuir `null` manualmente. Mesmo assim mantenho minha resposta devido à estrutura, e adicionalmente recomendo o método [IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx) para usuários do .NET 4 e superiores.

Answer (score 1):

Olá amigos consegui resolver meu problemas com esse método

```
public bool VerificarCamposEmBranco(Control ctrl)
{
    bool retorno = false;
    foreach (Control c in ctrl.Controls)
    {
        if (c is TextBox)
        {
            if (((TextBox)c).Text.Length <= 2)
            {
                //Campo ta em branco
                retorno = true;
                //((TextBox)c).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                MessageBox.Show("Preencha o campo" + c.Name);
            }
        }
    }

    return retorno;
}
```

Muito obrigado pela ajuda....